# .project file missing in Eclipse but can be seen in Win Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven

I am using Eclipse Luna.  I working on a couple of projects before the weekend.  Win 7 did a magical reboot/install and this morning none of my class files are being shown in the Package Explorer within Eclipse.  I have checked the path to my files locally via GIT and they are all there including the POM and .project files.  but Explorere is complaining that the resources do not exist.  I have tried opening the project and I get:

> The project description file (.project) for 'brightside' is missing. 
>   This file contains important information about the project.  The
>   project will not function properly until this file is restored.

But the .project file in my GIT path.  To also add the folders color in the Package Explorer are now Blue.

Any advice to get me back to a productive status would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: "locally via GIT"? Why don't you check via command line `dir /a`, that's the direct way to check it.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse's view of the file system may be inconsistent after the forced exit.

First thing to do when a workspace was not cleanly closed: select the project(s) in question and refresh (`F5`).

If that doesn't help the next level would be: launch Eclipse with `-clean` command line option.

Additionally the Package Explorer may be hiding `.*` files, check `Filters ...` in the Package Explorer's view menu.